# Parsing string by awk and get only elements without pipes or semi colons

Tags: shell, grep, awk

I would like get this string line

```
AUGUSTYN|Stanisław|3589238
```

without `|` and `:`

I tried something like that:

```
cat baza|grep "AUGUSTYN" -n|awk -F '|' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'`
```

(`baza` is my file with text, and `AUGUSTYN` is the name of person)

Result of this command is:

```
1:AUGUSTYN Stanisław 3589238
```

As you see there still this pipe :( And I would like to get this:

```
1 AUGUSTYN Stanisław 3589238
```

I take text from this base file:

```
AUGUSTYN|Stanisław|3589238
BARAN|Stanisław|3511477
BUCZEK|Marek|3511526
CABAJ|Wanda|3511483
CEPAK|Józef|3511067
```

Getting strings without `|` and `:` would be great but I will have to get the number of line where this text is stored. So I had to use grep. If you can find any other more obvious solution for this too It would be mega great.

How can I archieve it? I started it learning an hour ago this awk. Please help.

Comment: Try `-F '[|:]'`. That removes both pipes and semi colons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` is not necessary, you can do this with `awk` alone:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} $1 == "AUGUSTYN" { print NR " " $1 " " $2 " " $3}'
```

Comment: +1. You can take advantage of awk's output field separator (default a space) like this: `awk -F\| '{$1=$1; print NR, $0}'` -- the `$1=$1` part forces awk to rewrite the input line using the output field separator. This method allows you to avoid hardcoding the number of fields.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `| sed "s/:/ /"` at the end of your command? so it's like this

```
cat baza|grep "AUGUSTYN" -n|awk -F '|' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' | sed "s/:/ /"
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding you and you want to do that in 1 command.